# Export object from three.js to anything

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there any way to export object from three.js? Any one will do : Collada,Blender,3ds Max,Maya

There is import plugin for blender (in [master](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) branch) but it's not working (can't even import exported cube), I tried to look in [dev](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender) branch for updated version, but there is no importer, only exporter

Consider this workflow : User generates some objects/models in browser(three.js) and than I want to import these objects into 3d modeling software for further editing/post modeling

Comment: far as i know there is only an import function in three.js. its a rendering engine. if you'd like to export you'd have to make a call to a php/asp/serverside script which saves the file to the hd.

Comment: @KevinKuyl That's correct, but I still need such a script

Comment: I'm confused, are you looking for importer or exporter? because you mention both in the question... In any case please have a look in three.js editor (http://threejs.org/editor) which has a menu with both import and export as well. test if its work for you and if so, the editor code is public so you can easily take the relevant code for yours

Comment: @meirm it has import/export in to json. What I need is ability to import this json into another 3d modeling software (3ds max, maya)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite a question. As far as i know 3ds max or maya have no option to import JSON files. You'll have to export as something that 3ds max and maya can import. An OBJ file would be one option.

The first thing you need to do is to create the obj file as a string.
The explanation of how an obj file is made can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).

Now its just a matter of a few simple loops to get the data from `scene.children` and generate the obj.

Once you generated the obj, you can send it to a server which saves it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool I used to use from MrDoob to export my meshes into a format that three.js can easily incorporate.
[Github to Mr.Doobs export tool](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r92)
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r92